# Neural Network with California Housing Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I tried to code a neural network which is trained on the California housing dataset, which I got from Aurelion Geron's GitHup.
But when I run the code, the net does not get trained and loss = nan.
Can someone explain what I did wrong?
Best regards, Robin

Link for the csv file: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/tree/master/datasets/housing

My Code:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("housing.csv", delimiter=",", header=0)
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
Y = df["median_house_value"].values
X = df.drop("median_house_value", axis=1)
# Inland / Not Inland -> True / False = 1 / 0
X["ocean_proximity"] = X["ocean_proximity"]== "INLAND"
X=X.values


X= X.astype(float)
Y= Y.astype(float)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu", input_dim=9))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")


model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=1000, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, there was a missing value in the "total_bedrooms" column

Answer (score 1):

You need to **drop NaN** values from you data.

After having a quick look at data, you also need to **normalize** your data (as everytime with Neural Nets, to help convergence).

To do this you can use **Standard Scaler**, Min-Max Scaler etc..

Answer (score 1):

nan values in your DataFrame are causing this behavior. Drop rows with the nan values and normalize your data:

```
df = df[~df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
df.iloc[:,:-1]=((df.iloc[:,:-1]-df.iloc[:,:-1].min())/(df.iloc[:,:-1].max()-df.iloc[:,:-1].min()))
```

And you will get:

```
Epoch 1/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.1732
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.1001
Epoch 2/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0527
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 3us/step - loss: 0.0430
Epoch 3/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0388
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0338
Epoch 4/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0301
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0288
Epoch 5/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0300
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0259
Epoch 6/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0235
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 3us/step - loss: 0.0238
Epoch 7/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0242
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0225
Epoch 8/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0213
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0218
Epoch 9/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0228
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0214
Epoch 10/50
 1000/20433 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0206
20433/20433 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 0.0211
```